# Mixed types of parameters in a router in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

My Node.js Express web application has two routes.

```
/* Route 1 renders the location view */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var locationId = parseInt(req.params.id); 

  console.log(locationId);
  // DO SOMETHING
  res.render('location');
});


/* Route 2 renders the map view */
router.get('/map', function(req, res, next) {
  // DO SOMETHING
  res.render('map');
});
```

The issue is when I passed /map in the URL, it was always directed to route 1 and rendered the location view instead of map. Was there anything wrong?

Comment: can you please  add your entry point file code index.js or app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express Route order : "first come, server first".

I guess following will work-

```
/* Route 2 First */
router.get('/map', function(req, res, next) {
  // DO SOMETHING
  res.render('map');
});
/* Route 1 renders the location view */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var locationId = parseInt(req.params.id); 

  console.log(locationId);
  // DO SOMETHING
  res.render('location');
});
```